# Yii.  CActiveForm. Response при ajax.

Tags: yii

Добрый день! Вопрос по виджету CActiveForm. Как получить в JavaScript response от сервера при ajax запросе? Т.е. что-то подобное как success: function() {}. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не очень понятно, что хотите. Но вот типовой пример аякс-кнопки.

```
echo CHtml::ajaxButton("Button",
    CController::createUrl('/site/index'),
    array('type' => 'POST',
        'data'=>array('id'=>'1'),       
        "success" => "js:function(html){ alert(html.responseText); }"
    )
);
```

---

```
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array('enableAjaxValidation'=>true));
...
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Отправить', '', array('type' => 'POST','update' => '#ajaxresult'), array('type' => 'submit'));
$this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но, к сожалению, немного не то. Я имею ввиду возможность использования "штатных средств" самого Yii в самом виджете CActiveForm, без использования класса CHtml.

Comment: Может так? 
Вы сами чётко представляете, что именно хотите?